# The values of the "num" and "den" properties must be row vectors or cell arrays of row vectors, where each vector is nonempty

Tags: matlab

I am quite new to **Matlab**. I want to plot for the following equation in **Matlab**.

```
G(s)= 1* (e-0.5s) /(s+1) (s+5)^2
```

When, I type in **Matlab**  like this,

```
clear all

clc

syms s

Gnum=exp(-0.5*s);

Gden=((s+1)*((s+5)^2));

G= tf (Gnum,Gden)

H=1

T= feedback (G,H)

step(T)
```

But I encountered error as per below.

```
??? Error using ==> tf.tf at 239
```

The values of the "**num**" and "**den**" properties must be row vectors or cell
arrays of row vectors, where each vector is nonempty and containing
numeric data. Type "**ltiprops tf**" for more information.

```
Error in ==> Untitled4 at 7

G= tf (Gnum,Gden)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing things very badly. You can't make `s` syms and then make transfer function using it.
Also, you do not `plot` a transfer function. You should use Bode on it to show the frequency and the magnitude of the transfer function for that. Just forget about syms all together when using Matlab control systems.

```
s=tf('s');
sys=exp(-0.5*s)/((s+1)*(s+5)^2)    
sys =     
                           1
  exp(-0.5*s) * ------------------------
                s^3 + 11 s^2 + 35 s + 25

Continuous-time transfer function.

sysf= feedback (sys,1);
step(sysf)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

If all you are wanting to do is plot that function, then something along the lines of this should suffice:

```
s = -10:.5:10;

G = 1 .* (exp(1)-0.5.*s) ./ (s+1) .* (s+5).^2;

plot(s,G)
```

[image: Plotted Graph]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ezplot` too if you want to plot `G(s)` where:

```
G(s)=exp(-0.5*s)/((s+1)*((s+5)^2));
```

You can use `ezplot` as follows:

```
ezplot('exp(-0.5*s)/((s+1)*((s+5)^2))');
```

to generate the following image:

[image]